# How to do alphanumeric sort in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection like this.

```
{"userID" : "TR31"}
{"userID" : "TR1059"}
{"userID" : "TR1043"}
```

I want to sort this document in an ascending or descending order, I tried this way `db.col.find({}).sort({"userID" : 1})` and `db.col.find({}).sort({"userID" : -1})`  but no luck.

Expected Result:

```
    {"userID" : "TR31"}
    {"userID" : "TR1043"}
    {"userID" : "TR1059"}
```

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`collation`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/#collation-document) with `numericOrdering` set to true in 3.4.

Something like

```
db.col.find({}).sort({"userID" : 1}).collation( { locale: "en_US", numericOrdering: true });
```

Answer (score 2):

One approach is, you need to save using a prefix.

```
{"userID" : "TR0031"},
{"userID" : "TR1059"},
{"userID" : "TR1043"}
```

so that you can achieve as you expect.

```
{"userID" : "TR0031"},
{"userID" : "TR1043"},
{"userID" : "TR1059"}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can't change this format because it's already in live.